# Why do I get 'Missing or insufficient permissions'?

Tags: firebase, flutter

When I try to sign in with google, the error arises:

```
W/Firestore( 9373): (22.0.1) [WriteStream]: (c17fcd5) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.

W/Firestore( 9373): (22.0.1) [Firestore]: Write failed at users/hc4f1aKFCFhr7mUgBlWfOyGgIIk1: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

E/flutter ( 9373): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

E/flutter ( 9373): #0      MethodChannelDocumentReference.set (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:43:7) E/flutter ( 9373): <asynchronous suspension> E/flutter ( 9373): #1     DocumentReference.set (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:78:22) E/flutter ( 9373): #2      DatabaseMethods.addUserInfoToDB (package:messenger_clone/services/database.dart:5:71) E/flutter ( 9373): #3      AuthMethods.signInWithGoogle (package:messenger_clone/services/auth.dart:46:25) E/flutter ( 9373):
#4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47) E/flutter ( 9373): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19) E/flutter ( 9373): #6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18) E/flutter ( 9373): #7      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45) E/flutter ( 9373): #8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32) E/flutter ( 9373): #9      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5) E/flutter ( 9373): #10    
_AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15) E/flutter ( 9373): #11    
_completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13) E/flutter ( 9373): #12     FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart) E/flutter ( 9373): #13 
_rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47) E/flutter ( 9373): #14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19) E/flutter ( 9373): #15     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18) E/flutter ( 9373): #16     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45) E/flutter ( 9373): #17     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32) E/flutter ( 9373): #18     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5) E/flutter ( 9373): #19    
_AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15) E/flutter ( 9373): #20    
_completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13) E/flutter ( 9373): #21     MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart) E/flutter ( 9373): #22     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47) E/flutter ( 9373): #23    
_CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19) E/flutter ( 9373): #24     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18) E/flutter ( 9373): #25     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45) E/flutter ( 9373): #26     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32) E/flutter ( 9373): #27     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5) E/flutter ( 9373): #28    
_AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15) E/flutter ( 9373): #29    
_completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13) E/flutter ( 9373): #30     MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart) E/flutter ( 9373): #31     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47) E/flutter ( 9373): #32     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19) E/flutter ( 9373): #33     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18) E/flutter ( 9373): #34     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45) E/flutter ( 9373): #35     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32) E/flutter ( 9373): #36     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5) E/flutter ( 9373): #37    
_AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15) E/flutter ( 9373): #38    
_completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13) E/flutter ( 9373): #39     MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart) E/flutter ( 9373): #40     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47) E/flutter ( 9373): #41     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19) E/flutter ( 9373): #42     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18) E/flutter ( 9373): #43     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45) E/flutter ( 9373): #44     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32) E/flutter ( 9373): #45     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5) E/flutter ( 9373): #46     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7) E/flutter ( 9373): #47    
_rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13) E/flutter ( 9373): #48     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19) E/flutter ( 9373): #49     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7) E/flutter ( 9373): #50     _CustomZone.b
```

I tried to edit rulles like this but seems it doen't work

```
allow read: if auth != null;  
allow write: if auth != null;
```

but when I check the firebase authentificated users, the logged in google user is there.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are trying to make signing ?

Comment: @dm_tr I've changed the firebase database rulles to this `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;` and it works, do you think the was an issue with the code where I'm trying to make signing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your Rule as below

```
allow read: if request.auth != null;  
allow write: if request.auth != null;
```